"[" displayed as "Ä" and "]" displayed as "Å" in remote terminal from vscode
I did the following things in VSCODE:

remote ssh into a remote virtual machine;
opened a terminal;
typed some characters into the terminal.

I then noticed that [ is displayed as Ä and ] is displayed as Å in remote terminal from the vscode. I also confirmed that before remote ssh, characters in local terminal are correct. Further, my local machine is windows and executing "locale" on on bash session from remote server through vscode provides me the following result:
bash-4.4$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Further, as I got no problem on the server without going through vscode, I ran "locale" there and got the following:
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

There has to be some encoding decoding issue on vscode-server, in my understanding. Can anyone tell me how to fix it from vscode?

Before you ssh, run locale on the local system. Then ssh to the remote system and run locale there. Put both sets of results into your question. It's likely they are different

From your description it seems like you've run locale on the remote server both times. That doesn't help for identifying differences between the local system and the remote

[ and ] correspond to to Ä and Å in Swedish and Finnish branches of ISO Latin.
